# JDBC: How to clear the contents of a result set before using it again?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, multiple-resultsets

I want to clear the contents of a result set (but nothing should happen to the underlying database) before using it again to execute a new query?

**Is there any method which will delete its data (but do nothing to the underlying database, that's important), so that I can use the same resultset again to retrieve data from another query?**

*A quick search in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) gave me the idea that deleting things through a method like* `deleteRow()` *will actually delete data from the database as well.* *I just want to reset/refresh/clear the resultSet, so that when it is again used to get results of another query, it should contain data from that query only, and not the previous one.*

Or **does it automatically remove its contents itself once** we have retrieved them from it (through methods like `ResultSet.getInt()`, `ResultSet.getString()` etc.)

**EDIT:-**
**Can we create new result sets for executing each query in the same method?**

Comment: If you no longer need the values in a resultset object you could use the same resultset object for the next query which would overwrite the old values.

Comment: You don't use a resultset to execute a query. A resultset is the result of a query execution. If you want to release the resources associated with a resultset, you must close it, as explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29).

Comment: @Jay Suppose we retreive values from it into an ArrayList, and the first query returned three values, and the second returned 2 values. The first two values will be over-written, good enough, but what about the third value in the ResultSet (which was from the first query), shall it still be there?

Comment: @JBNizet That releases the database itself? And now there is another question, when the database is released by a ResultSet, is it also released by the Connection?

Comment: A database can't be released. That doesn't make any sense. The close() method does what the javadoc says it does.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh yes, I had misinterpreted this statement from the API: "Releases this ResultSet object's database and JDBC resources immediately..." Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you want to execute a query like this :

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from people");
```

You would iterate of the results with something like this:

```
while(result.next()) {
    // ... get column values from this record
}
```

Then you just reuse the variable `rs` to execute another query like:

```
rs = statement2.executeQuery("select * from cars");
```

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html) is a tutorial on working with ResultSet